# neural network with mostly zero target

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am very new to neural networks. I have a dataset that contains 16M records, in which only 70K are labeled 1 and the rest are 0 (even by setting some special restrictions the total would not be less than 2.5M records in which 58K is labeled 1, and the restriction is not fully logical as well). Is there any special practice to deal with this kind of data?

Now if I just write a function to always return 0, the accuracy would be 99.56% ! Is neural network an appropriate option at all? If no, what is my alternative and if yes, how should deal with it?

tnx

Comment: Google "class imbalance", which is a huge subtopic in itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to give a higher weight to samples labeled 1 or sample minibatches from both classes separately, such that the network is shown the same number of examples from both classes.

For the first method, frameworks such as Keras give an option to include a weight factor for every class:

```
class_weights = {
    0: 1.0,
    1: 43.0,
}

model.fit(X, y, ..., class_weight=class_weights)
```

scikit-learn has a method of computing the class weights automatically, as shown in [this comment on Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/jigsaw-toxic-comment-classification-challenge/discussion/46673)

Accuracy is not a good way to measure the performance of the network in this case. Precision, recall for the class 1 or similar measures might give a better understanding of the performance of the model.